# Extraction of Activated Carbon from Lignin

Tags: materials, carbon-allotropes

I'm currently working on a research project which involves the extraction of activated carbon from lignin. I'm already aware of the method of preparation using an alkali along with lignin products but I'm looking for more offbeat ideas that haven't been done before. Some suggestions would be great.

Comment: Extraction is the wrong word.